# Can I make .gdbinit YES to "Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?"

Tags: gdb

When I start gdb I routinely want to `break my_function`. I can add this command to `.gdbinit` but I get

```
Function "my_function" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

(This is because `my_function` is dynamically linked.)

How do I make it non-interactively take an affirmative answer to this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `set breakpoint pending on` in `.gdbinit` anywhere before `break my_function`.
See gdb [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html):

> set breakpoint pending on
>
> This indicates that an unrecognized breakpoint location should automatically result in a pending breakpoint being created.

Comment: Does this work? I tried to add this line before "skip ..." statements and no difference.

Comment: Yes it does. What if you remove `skip` statements? If it still does not work I'd suggest to [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: confirmed. My company has old centos which won't work. But newer version worked.